# Hi. I got tomcat error HTTP status report 404 - not found

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm bioinformatian and  I want to install one web-based program called GNOMEX which is LIMS(Laboratory Information Management System). This is my first time to using tomcat and JAVA. So it would be really helpful if you guys help me :) ...

It is using Tomcat 7. I set homepath for catalina. And when I can see tomcat page in localhost:8080 after I type sh `start.sh`.

I want to access to http://www.localhost:8080/gnomex/gnomexFlex.jsp
but I got error message.

> HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
>
> Type Status Report
>
> Message /gnomex/gnomexFlex.jsp
>
> Description The origin server did not find a current representation
>   for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

what did I check

1. I followed every step in the installation guide.
2. I checked `$CATALINA_PATH`
3. I checked root folder is webapps in `server.xml`
4. I checked I add `gnomex.war` in webapps ( i heard this is kind of container )
5. I checked there is a file gnomexFlex.jsp in webapps/gnomex/

i don't know how to find the problems....so i looked into logs. let's see what is written. I guess there are clues.  :( please help me. I spend my week to install this, and spend another week to figure this out... thanks.

```
Nov 08, 2018 12:29:38 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive /home/eunhae/apache-tomcat-7.0.91/webapps/gnomex.war java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/gnomex]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1022)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:994)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1127)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:2021)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

logs

```
Nov 08, 2018 12:17:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:560)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:654)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:679)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed) <null>:8080
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:413)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:728)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:452)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)


Nov 08, 2018 12:17:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 08, 2018 12:17:20 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed) <null>:8009
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:413)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:728)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:452)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:560)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:840)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:654)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:679)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:427)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use (Bind failed)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:387)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:400)

Nov 08, 2018 12:17:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.91
Nov 08, 2018 12:17:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/log4j/Logger;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:138)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:417)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5566)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1928)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1771)
        ... 20 more
Nov 08, 2018 12:17:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:444)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:758)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:705)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1707)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1697)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1254)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:819)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1243)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/apache/log4j/Logger;
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:138)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:417)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:388)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5566)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1928)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1771)
        ... 20 more

Nov 08, 2018 12:17:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 08, 2018 12:17:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 08, 2018 12:17:24 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Nov 08, 2018 12:17:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 08, 2018 12:17:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 08, 2018 12:17:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 08, 2018 12:17:24 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 08, 2018 12:17:24 AM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources cleanUp
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class loader
        at org.apache.naming.ContextBindings.getClassLoader(ContextBindings.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.cleanUp(NamingResources.java:1011)
        at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResources.stopInternal(NamingResources.java:994)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5894)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:259)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1149)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1364)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:1149)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1364)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:594)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:709)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:428)
```

server.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.

  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
     define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
     Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
 -->
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
  -->
  <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-howto.html -->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
  <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <!-- Global JNDI resources
       Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
  -->
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>

  <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
       a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
       so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
       Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
   -->
  <Service name="Catalina">

    <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more named thread pools-->
    <!--
    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
        maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
    -->


    <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
         and responses are returned. Documentation at :
         Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
         Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
         APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
         Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
    -->
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->

   <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
               port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
    -->
    <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
         This connector uses the BIO implementation that requires the JSSE
         style configuration. When using the APR/native implementation, the
         OpenSSL style configuration is required as described in the APR/native
         documentation -->
    <!--
    <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
    -->

    <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


    <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
         every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
         analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
         on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
         Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

    <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
    -->
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
          /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
          /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
      <!--
      <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
      -->

      <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
           via a brute-force attack -->
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <!-- This Realm uses the UserDatabase configured in the global JNDI
             resources under the key "UserDatabase".  Any edits
             that are performed against this UserDatabase are immediately
             available for use by the Realm.  -->
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
              unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

[GNOMEX installation guide](http://hci-bio-demo.hci.utah.edu/gnomexDocumentation/wordpress/?page_id=980)

Comment: Do you have other error messages / stack traces in the logs ? You usually have `Caused by :` stack traces which lead to the real problem.

Comment: If you can see Tomcat page in 8080 port then probably there's no service available for your path.So check for this Context /gnomex

Comment: Can we please have your server.xml?

Comment: @Arnaud  there are! Actually, so many. I added that code in my post!

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis Thanks for answering me :) I didn't get it. Could  you explain more specifically? :P

Comment: @TsakiroglouFotis Okay. I added server.xml in my post

Comment: is this the actual server.xml file? I think it's malformed and tomcat shouldn't even start with this file. Right after ther tomcatThreadPool, there's a  close comment `-->` without an opening comment `<!--` before it

Comment: can you post your `catalina.sh` file too since the installation guide require you to make changes to it

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that you can check on.

1. `Address already in use (Bind failed) <null>:8080`  this usually means that you have another service using the port. Possibly you tried to run Tomcat again without shutting down the previous one completely.
2. `NoClassDefFoundError:`  this usually means that you have some dependencies not fulfilled. Did you make sure that you copied all the jar files to the `lib` folder?
3. `SEVERE: Error deploying web application archive` this means that Tomcat is trying to deploy the war file but failed. There could be many reasons for this. Did you bump up the header and post size as mentioned in the installation guide?

`<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               maxHttpHeaderSize="1048576"
               maxPostSize="67589953"
               redirectPort="8443" />`

4. What about your MySQL? Have you set it up? Did you created the database as instructed?

Comment: yes I created MySQL and checked database is created. :)  i'll check 1,2,3 when I go to lab. thanks!

Comment: 1. i think that issue is from mistakes that i didnd not turn off tomcat and tried to run it again.

Comment: 2. I remember i did it but I checked it. some files were missing so i i added all jar files !

Comment: 3. I checked, i found out that i didn't bump up the header and post size. i adjusted it.

Comment: I checked 4 possibles ways that possibly causes error. So i ran it again, i got same answer < not found 404> .  I'll add new error code... :< if you are not busy, can you help me?

Comment: I believe some of the issues above are not happening anymore. Please update the new error logs for further debugging.